# I am using the TSL Mastodon API, I wrote a simple function to grab images from a url and upload them to Mastodon but getting unexpected results

Tags: javascript, typescript, mastodon

This the block of code the grabs and uploads the image

```
async MediaUpload(photos : any[]) 
{ 
    const client = await this.Login() 
    const full_photo_urls : string[] = photos.map((item) => item.full) 
    let image_ids : string[] = []; 
    full_photo_urls.forEach(async (image_url) => { 
        const image_blob = await fetch(image_url).then(res => res.blob()) 
        try { 
            console.log("images are about to be posted!"); 
            const image_res = await client.postMediaAttachment({file: image_blob}) 
            console.log("Images were posted here"); console.log(image_res); } 
            catch (error) { 
                console.error(error); 
            } }
            ) 
            return image_ids;
        }
```

the upload happens and I get status 200, however this does result in a failure and the catch block is ran

Output of error:

```
{
   "failed":true,
   "json":{
      "id":"111037763715692057",
      "type":"image",
      "url":"https://files.botsin.space/media_attachments/files/111/037/763/715/692/057/original/c46fd6ce6b892c66.jpeg",
      "preview_url":"https://files.botsin.space/media_attachments/files/111/037/763/715/692/057/small/c46fd6ce6b892c66.jpeg",
      "remote_url":null,
      "preview_remote_url":null,
      "text_url":null,
      "meta":{
         "original":[
            "Object"
         ],
         "small":[
            "Object"
         ]
      },
      "description":null,
      "blurhash":"UEHo8yIm%gV?9Exv%fM{?u~qM_D%xvITM{xa"
   },
   "path":"media",
   "response":"Response"{
      [
         "Symbol(realm)"
      ]:null,
      [
         "Symbol(state)"
      ]:{
         "aborted":false,
         "rangeRequested":false,
         "timingAllowPassed":true,
         "requestIncludesCredentials":true,
         "type":"default",
         "status":200,
         "timingInfo":[
            "Object"
         ],
         "cacheState":"",
         "statusText":"OK",
         "headersList":[
            "HeadersList"
         ],
         "urlList":[
            "Array"
         ],
         "body":[
            "Object"
         ]
      },
      [
         "Symbol(headers)"
      ]:"HeadersList"{
         "cookies":null,
         [
            "Symbol(headers map)"
         ]:[
            "Map"
         ],
         [
            "Symbol(headers map sorted)"
         ]:null
      }
   },
   "status":200,
   "rateLimit":30
}
```

as you can see the status code is 200 which I would assume mean I can print the result (this is only for testing, usually would get added to image_ids array and than returned)

I am expecting this code to not result in an error and continue running as normally

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This was resolved and was due to a bug in the TSL Mastodon API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the TSL Mastodon API that causes an error if a focus point was not provided!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).